# script onload not firing in Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, script-tag

I'm trying to load jQuery conditionally and the onload function is not being called when running my app on android devices. It does work in Chrome and iPhone.

```
    if (!window.jQuery) { 
        var jqscript   = document.createElement("script");
        jqscript.type  = "text/javascript";
        jqscript.src   = "js/lib/jQuery.js";
        document.body.appendChild(jqscript);
        jqscript.onload = jqLoaded;
    }
```

.

```
function jqLoaded(){
    jQuery.noConflict();
    alert('jqueryloaded');
}
```

I'm probably going to forget about the conditional loading, but is there any reason this shouldn't work?

Comment: Have you tried putting it before the call to .appendChild() ?

Comment: Is the page you're accessing (the one running the code) on the web or just locally on your phone?

Comment: This is why everyone uses jQuery. If there is one library that you want on every page, this would be it.

Comment: @Nelson I did just now.. made sense, but.. still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @shibniggurath it's a local webview (phonegap app).

Comment: Check out the path is ok `js/lib/jQuery.js` especially the case sensitive name `jQuery.js` file..

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
document.body.appendChild(jqscript);
```

to

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqscript);
```